# Install Sample data fails on joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I tried and installed the JA Blazes quick start template (which includes all the modules and extensions, as shown in their live demo) for Joomla 1.5 on my local server and all worked perfectly well, but when I installed it on my domain server, the install sample data fails. I do see the DB being updated, but the installation just never ends. The installation of sample data goes on forever. Is there a way I can figure out if something went/is-going wrong ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like the connection with the db server is timing out.
If you can work out where the sql files are stored within the distribution (usually /installation/sql/ ) you could insert the sql manually using phpMyAdmin or from the command line.

If the demo installed fine on your local machine there is no need to 'install' it at all on the remote server.

FTP all of the files up to the server.
Use phpMyAdmin locally to export the database
Use phpMyAdmin on the remote server to import the backed up sql.
Finally edit the configuration.php file with the database details and paths for the remote server.

A final alternative would be to utilise Akeeba Backup or similar to package up the site and move it from local to remote. This is a fantastic tool that works around most memory limits and other annoyances on shared hosting.